# Adjusting Buttons and Text Field in a Div

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to develop a Integer Number Field. I've got it working but the styling is somewhat creating a problem. I'm using Glyphicons Plus and Minus to act as increment and decrement functionalities and input text field to display the Integer number.

I'm not able to adjust the Minus Glyphicon to the height of the div.
The working code: http://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/fv4jxo4t/26/

HTML code:

```
 <div> 
        <a>
        <button (click)="decrement()" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></i></span>
        </button>
        </a>
        <input type="text" style="width:45%;" [(ngModel)]="count">
       <a>
        <button (click)="increment()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i></span>
        </button>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
 div {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid #CACEDB;
        width: 162px;
        height:38px;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-radius:3px;
        }
    input{
        text-align: center;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        border:none;
    }
    input:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
    button
    {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        outline: none;
        height:100%; 
        border:none;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

button:active {
    background-color: #015191;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fv4jxo4t/27/ all i did was remove the height:38px on `div` and now it's the same hight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your minus button needs a float:left :

```
 <div> 
    <a>
        <button (click)="decrement()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left;">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></i></span>
        </button>
    </a>
    <input type="text" style="width:45%;" [(ngModel)]="count">
    <a>
        <button (click)="increment()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;">
            <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i></span>
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Bootstrap you can make use of the `input-group` class alongside `input-group-btn`.  Reference the CodePen link below:

http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/JKOyom

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Integer">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></span>
</div>
```

I would also recommend not wrapping your `<button>` in an `<a>` tag.  The `<button>` can function on a JS event on its own and the code is cleaner.